# Roaming Profile Accounts logoff instantly

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-8.1

I am working on setting up roaming profile accounts. When I log in as one of my users, they disconnect instantly.

How do I find errors on what is going on?

I've check the SMB Share permissions and as far as I can tell they look good. [I followed this guide on Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079.aspx).

I can login fine with my account that is setup as the enterprise admin. local admin account works fine too.

Comment: What do you mean by "they disconnect"?

Comment: Solved it. Finally came to me when I was writing this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing RDP connections, so I needed to allow the groups to connect remotely/lower the remote security level.